# Can someone briefly explain the underlying concepts behind the Boltzmann Distribution?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics

According to Wikipedia, the probability of finding a particle being in a specific energy state as a function of that state's energy and the temperature of the system is given by:

[image]

I understand all of the mathematics involved. But what does this equation mean on an intuitive level? What is the meaning of the partition function and the expression in the numerator, and why together do they give this probability?

Thank you

Comment: Well think about it this way, each of the $p_i$'s are positive right? And they sum up to $1$? Then they can represent a probability for events happening. Really from that equation alone the partition function is just serving as a normalisation, but it's usefulness is in what you can compute from it. Intuitively though a state is more likely to be occupied $1.$ if the temperature is high, just think of the function $e^{-x/\lambda}$ and plot for increasing $\lambda$. $2.$ if the energy is low. Think of plotting $e^{-\alpha x}$ for $\alpha$ getting close to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is proportional to $e^{-\epsilon_i/kT}$. Let $C$ be the proportionality constant. Then
$$p_i=Ce^{-\epsilon_i/kT}$$
By normalization of probability, we have
$$\sum_i p_i=\sum_i Ce^{-\epsilon_i/kT}=C\sum_ie^{-\epsilon_i/kT}=1$$

Hence
$$C=\frac{1}{\sum_ie^{-\epsilon_i/kT}}$$
and
$$p_i=\frac{1}{\sum_je^{-\epsilon_j/kT}}e^{-\epsilon_i/kT}$$